# WearOS : JetpackCompose : Disable Quick panel on particular Activity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, swipe-gesture, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to disable a quick panel when swipe down that show in wearOS watch in samsung watch 4 or above new model version of watch , is there any ways to disable this or not please give me some idea or details explanation if that is not possible , Thanks .

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? @Sunny Patel?

Comment: I'm also very interested in solution. My App is using a pulldown menu from the top and the Quick Panel on the Samsung Galaxy watch 4 and higher is preventing it to open properly. On other watches (at least the ones I've seen) with Wear OS 3.x and higher this type of system menu can only be opened from the main watch face. Would be nice if my App users can experience it for 100% without Samsun interfering with their own OneUI menus.